# Are there any online applications that are compatible with tablets?

Tags: drawing-tablet

as far as I can see, Wacom seems to be the only manufacturer of tablets who also developed a web driver. But are there any web sites which make use of a tablet?

Comment: I believe DeviantArt Muro has that support. Why anyone would want to use web application over some sort of desktop app, goes beyond my understanding.

Comment: @Joonas: yes, it works! Please submit your answer as answer :-)